# Wrong example of derivative of algebra in Sadri Hassani's mathematical physics book?

Tags: abstract-algebra, derivatives

The definition of the derivative of an algebra:

> Definition 3.4.1 A vector space endomorphism $\mathbf D$ : $\mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ is called a derivation on $\mathcal{A}$ if it has the additional property
> $$
> \mathbf{D}(\mathbf{a b})=\lceil\mathbf{D}(\mathbf{a})\rceil \mathbf{b}+\mathbf{a}[\mathbf{D}(\mathbf{b})\rceil
> $$

And he gave an example that all the algebra $C^r(a,b)$, i.e., all the function in interval $(a,b)$ have derivatives up to order $r$ with multiplication defined as $(f g)(t) \equiv f(t) g(t) \quad \forall t \in(a, b)$. And the  ordinary differentiation is a derivative of $C^r(a,b)$.

**My question is**, differentiation will map a function $f$ to $f^\prime$ while might have derivative up to order $r-1$ instead of $r$, hence the map is not endomorphism, then how can we say that this map is an example of the derivative of an algebra?

Comment: You are completely right. The author should have said that it was a derivation $C^\infty\to C^{\infty}$.

Comment: You're right, it should be $C^{\infty}$ otherwise it's not even an endomorphism.

Comment: A way to formalize the derivative $C^r\to C^{r-1}$ in terms of derivations would be to consider a $K$-algebra $A$, an $A$-bimodule $M$ and define derivations to be the $K$-linear maps $D:A\to M$ such that $D(ab)=aD(b)+D(a)b$. With $K=\Bbb R$, $A=C^r$ and $M=C^{r-1}$, the derivative is a derivation $C^r\to C^{r-1}$.